# Чи транслітеруються марки та моделі автомобілів?

Tags: власні-назви

*Lamborghini Aventador* чи *Ламборґіні Авентадор*? [Українська Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamborghini_Aventador) подає скрізь оригінальну назву, а українську лише один раз на початку, в дужках.

Яке правило правопису тут слід застосовувати?

Comment: Мені здається, обидва варіанти (не транслітерувати чи транслітерувати) загалом прийнятні. Залежить від правил і мети майданчика, на якому Ви пишете (наприклад, у вікіпедії транслітерують, якщо є усталена транслітерація, і лишають оригінал в іншому випадку (бо вікіпедія має спиратися на усталені джерела, а не винаходити своє); десь, може, навпаки, недоречно буде лишати без транслітерації, бо основною аудиторією є читачі без знання іноземних мов).

Comment: Правопис лише каже ([§ 58.2](https://mon.gov.ua/storage/app/media/zagalna%20serednya/05062019-onovl-pravo.pdf#page=64)), що назви торгових марок автомобілів мають бути в лапках і з великої літери (хоча не завжди). Усі наведені там приклади марок автомобілів транслітеровані, але прямо про це нічого не сказано і в іншому параграфі ([§ 54.4-5](https://mon.gov.ua/storage/app/media/zagalna%20serednya/05062019-onovl-pravo.pdf#page=61)) одні й ті самі назви (_концерн «Volkswagen»_ vs. _концерн «Фольксваген»_) наведено і в оригінальному, і в транслітерованому вигляді (щоправда як назви підприємств).

Comment: Гадаю, ми не маємо припускати, що користувач знає латинську абетку і як вона читається, тому все має бути кирилицею.

Comment: @Yola, з одного боку, це слушна думка. А з іншого — у деяких контекстах, можливо, важливіше, щоб людина відразу розуміла, про що мова (якщо, припустімо, цю торгову марку всюди пишуть латиною), ніж щоб вона правильно вимовляла. Тому, по-моєму, це, знов-таки, залежить від контексту й того, як власник торгової марки себе подає (наприклад, «МакДональдз» у Росії транслітерує свою вивіску, а в Україні — ні, хоча на українському сайті свою назву таки транслітерує).

Comment: Я не правник, але після одної роботи, де мав декотрі справи з паперами, маю враженя, же всї назви, якщо зареєстровані в Україні, мають бути або перебуквовані, або перекладені. Чому? Бо так відбувало ся з назвами різних компаній.

Comment: @stegetsj, однак питання, чи зареєстрована ця марка в Україні (можливо, вона просто не продається тут).

Comment: А чому ви *gh* перебуквовуєте як *ґ?*

Comment: @Yola, так подає Вікіпедія.